# Can somone help me make this script more readable?

Tags: bash, scripts

```
SRC="/src"
export DEST="/dest"

find "${SRC}" -iname '*' -type f -exec bash -c 'EXT="${0##*.}"; EXT=${EXT,,}; if [[ "${EXT}" == *"/"* ]]; then EXT="no_extension"; fi; mkdir -p "${DEST}/${EXT}"; rsync -a "$0" "${DEST}/${EXT}"' "{}" \;
```

This script organizes SRC to DEST by using find to iterate all files in the SRC folder and on each file found, it performs the following:

1. Saves file extension into `EXT`
2. Convert `EXT` to lowercase
3. Does `EXT` contain a `/` character? If yes, then `EXT="no_extension"`
4. Create a new folder named `$EXT` in the `$DEST` folder
5. `rsync` the file to the folder just created. `-a` flag for extra-preservedness.

I want to add more to the script, like a function to ignore useless file types, but it's already hard to add code to.

How can I re-arrange this so it's easier to use?

EDIT: This is not original work, but it is modified by me. It's the only script I could understand that did what I wanted. But now I want to add more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the entire `bash` command to a script (say, in `/some/path/sync.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash

for i 
do
    EXT="${i##*.}" 
    EXT=${EXT,,}

    if [[ "${EXT}" == *"/"* ]]
    then 
        EXT="no_extension"; 
    fi

    mkdir -p "${DEST}/${EXT}"
    rsync -a "$i" "${DEST}/${EXT}"
done
```

Then call the `find` thus:

```
SRC="/src"
export DEST="/dest"

find "${SRC}" -iname '*' -type f -exec /some/path/sync.sh {} +
```

And now add all the functions you want.

In particular, to ignore useless file extensions, modifying the `find` command would be better:

```
find ... ! -regex '.*\.(some|useless|exts)$' ... -exec
```

(With some escaping of `(` and `|` and an appropriate choice of `-regextype`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check how readable is your script for a computer by checking the script by shellcheck.

For this, copy your actual script version, p.e. to the follow online version of shellcheck and see possible remarks or errors:

- https://www.shellcheck.net/

You can use shellcheck on terminal offline also, if you install it local, on follow way:

```
shellcheck path_to_your_script/your_script.sh
```